# PHP doesn't send Authorization header

Tags: php, http

This is my code

```
 // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init($serviceURL); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 

        // set body
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 


        $usernamePassword64Encoded = 'username,password';
        $usernamePassword64Encoded = base64_encode ( $usernamePassword64Encoded );

        //make the request content type as json
        $headers = array(
            'Content-type: application/json', 
            'Authorization:Basic '+$usernamePassword64Encoded,
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

in the server, i read the content type header, it is okay, but when i read the authorisation header, it is **null**

why? am i passing them wrong? (if i do, how can the content type is being read in the server? )

#### Update

adding this code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "Basic "+$usernamePassword64Encoded);
```

let the server receives the Authorization field, but the received value is:

> Basic MDo=

it is not correct, I send different value

#### Update 2

the current code

```
$ch = curl_init($serviceURL); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 

        // set body
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 


        $usernamePassword64Encoded = 'blabla,blabla';


        //make the request content type as json
        $headers = array(
            'Content-type: application/json', 
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $usernamePassword64Encoded);

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

my problem now is that i send `blabla,blabla` but i receive `blabla,blabla:`

notice the extra double dot at the end of the received value

Comment: Some browsers handle the headers differently. Have you tried it with multiple browsers?

Comment: @JefréN. no i tried it with just google chrome, but i don't know which one my client will use, so i prefer to solve it for all browsers, right?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your Code, maybe its because you read authorisation instead of authorization?

Comment: Why not use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password")` over building your own auth header? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32272006/4982088) is a simple example.

Comment: Check [this out](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) for what I mean about the header having to be *just right.*

Comment: This is literally the third EXACT same question regarding CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER within 2 days, all questions have no answers either. Your code is perfectly fine. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` only accepts an array

Comment: @Zanderwar `$headers` is an array..

Comment: Yeah, exactly; which makes your code fine.

Comment: @Xorifelse you would find that this is for an API that OP doesn't have control over, and this is a specific requirement of that API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289474/php-curl-http-post-request-set-custom-header-with-nested-key-value-pairs/39289582 just like this guy

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel no i ready Authorization , it was a type made by auto complete

Comment: @Zanderwar so what is the solution please?

Comment: @Xorifelse i want to send in the Authorization header, that is why the server understands, please help

Comment: @Xorifelse kindly check my updated question

Comment: @Zanderwar kindly check my updated question

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel kindly check my updated question

Comment: @JefréN. kindly check my updated question

Comment: The solution is A) **DONT SPAM** B) Contact the API owner

Comment: @Zanderwar: I *totally* did not get the point of that last comment... ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli are you **certain** `$usernamePassword64Encoded` is correct, "MDo=" decodes to `0`

Comment: i found the solution, i shouldn't send the Basic word, even though it is the standard in the http protocol, but the PHP library add it automatically

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli good work, now delete your question :P

Comment: The translated message of `MDo=` = `0:` so now it is receiving something. However, you are encoding your username and password in the same string, split them apart, encode and merge them like so: `"$encodeduser:$encodedpass"` removing the `"Basic"` string.

Comment: @Zanderwar: Ouch!

Comment: @Xorifelse no no , i shouldn't encode them, the library does that itself and it adds the required *Basic * + the space itself, now everything is working

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Glad to have helped.

Comment: @Xorifelse last thing please, i send username, password, but receive them (after decoding) the exact same as i sent but with extra **:** (double dot) at the end, why?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Can you post the full code after your update in the OP?

Comment: @Xorifelse i did now

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Change the `,` to a `:` in `$usernamePassword64Encoded`

Comment: @Xorifelse you are a genius , write an answer please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122705/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using:

```
$usr = 'user';
$pwd = 'pass';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$usr:$pwd");
```

And remove the `Authorization` header from the array.
This way, curl sets up its own auth header which should be fully complaint by most if not all browsers.

However, if the username or more likely the password contains a `:` character it would break, encoding should be used here.

```
$pwd = urlencode( 'my:complex:pass');
```

And obviously decoded at the other end.